# Discord SDK Send a message to all channels of the server where a command is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am developing the following command:
! sir snd all -hello

This command tells you to send the message after the "-" to all channels on the server where the command is sent.

This is what I have done so far:

```
 else if(command == 'snd'){
        if(suffix == 'all'){


             client.channels.cache.forEach( channel => {
                if(channel.type == "GUILD_TEXT") {  
                    channel.send(sParameter[1])
                 }
                });
        
            
          
            
            
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the following line of code:

```
client.channels.cache.forEach
```

It takes all the channels that the bot is part of; I would like to take only the channels of the server in which the message is sent.

In fact now, if I go to send that command, a message will be sent to all the text channels of all the servers of which the bot is part

Is there a solution to this? So to take the ids of the channels of the server where the command is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply get all the channels of the guild instead of all channels.
Like so:

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach( channel => {
                if(channel.type == "GUILD_TEXT") {  
                    channel.send(sParameter[1])
                 }
                });
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of it lmao